# Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory

There is a next Java code

```
public class PermGenSpace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                generate("com.dk.String" + i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        new Sample();
    }

    public static Class generate(String name) throws Exception {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        return pool.makeClass(name).toClass();
    }
}
```

I use Eclipse IDE. In "Run->Run Configuration" I setup next VM arguments:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1m -Xmx10m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

After that I expected that the "OutOfMemoruError:PermGen space" will throw. But I have

```
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the 
UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Could somebody explain me why? And how can I get OutOfMemoruError:PermGen space?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Presumably the OOM error is being thrown outside if a try/catch.

Comment: @SteveSmith OutOfMemoryError is an Error and does not extend Exception. So his catch won't have any effect on the OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: I guess that you tried to create a classloader leak but ended up with a regular OOM error instead. I think the perm size limit should be reached in an application server rather than a single app (but I may be completely wrong).

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS Exactly right (I put "a" try/catch, not "your" try catch).  If OP puts a `catch(Error...)` they'll get what (I think) they want.

Comment: What's `pool.makeClass(name).toClass();` doing? It looks like you're doing it a **billion** times after all. One billion bytes is a gigabyte, btw.